# Adding custom parameter(s) to function call bound to component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bind

#### Problem

While binding a function to a component in VueJS, I'm trying to pass in custom parameter(s), *and also* accept the parameter(s) supplied by that component to the same function.

#### Context

I'm adding a custom sort function to a Bootstrap-Vue table.

When calling this function, the table component passes [7 parameters](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-sort-compare-routine) into it.

My complication is that in order to sort a certain column, I need information from the outer scope, and so I want to dynamically pass that needed information into the sort function directly in the `v-bind` property. This is fine, except I can't figure out how to *both* pass in my custom parameter *as well as* accept the 7 parameters provided when Bootstrap-Vue calls my function internally.

Eg. I can call it like this:

```html
<b-table :sort-compare="sortTable" />
```

And get access to all 7 parameters in `sortTable()`.

But if I add my own to the list:

```html
<b-table :sort-compare="sortTable(myData)" />
```

I *only* have my one parameter instead, and the other 7 are lost.

Tried passing in `...arguments`, but that doesn't do what I want either.

#### Question

Is this possible? Is there a special Vue instance `$[property]` to use as a placeholder in bound function calls, like `$event` for event listeners, that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option here is to create a new function.

You can use an inline arrow function like this

```html
<b-table :sort-compare="(...args) => sortTable(myData, ...args)" />
```

```js
methods: {
  sortTable(data, a, b, key, desc, formatter, options, locale) {
    // do what you gotta do
  }
}
```

Of course, this can get pretty messy so you could use a method to create the function

```html
<b-table :sort-compare="createSortCompare(myData)" />
```

```js
methods: {
  createSortCompare(data) {
    return (a, b, key, desc, formatter, options, locale) => {
      // you now have access to all arguments as well as "data"
    }
  }
}
```